# Collect both min and max in one stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I need to print both min and max of a stream of int in one operation. I currently have 2 operations but the second is not allowed. Somehow collectors are not working for me:

```
Stream<Integer> stringInt = Stream.of(8,50,16,0,72);
System.out.println(stringInt.reduce(Math::min).get());
System.out.println(stringInt.reduce(Math::max).get());
```

Comment: @PaulRooney the return type is also a Stream<Integer> that happens to have only 2 elements. It's a challenge for code refactoring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second is not allowed since stream can not be reused. From [`Stream javadoc`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) :

> A stream should be operated on (invoking an intermediate or terminal stream operation) only once. This rules out, for example, "forked" streams, where the same source feeds two or more pipelines, or multiple traversals of the same stream. A stream implementation may throw IllegalStateException if it detects that the stream is being reused.

You could use `collect` with [`Collectors.summarizingInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#summarizingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) :

```
IntSummaryStatistics collect = stringInt.collect(Collectors.summarizingInt(value -> value));

System.out.println(collect.getMax());
System.out.println(collect.getMin());
```